# Do all iPad mini models have SIM slots?

Tags: ipad, sim

I currently have an iPad mini 2 WiFi/Verizon. It is a 16GB model.

I want to upgrade to a 128GB model and use my existing SIM card. Do I have to buy a Verizon model, or can I buy a so-called "WiFi-only" model and use my SIM?

Thanks all.

Comment: "Wifi only" means you can only access wifi not verizon.  If you also have an iPhone you may want to learn about instant hotspot. https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/continuity/ which will allow you to use the less expensive wifi only iPad and have it get it's internet connection via the iPhone.  (this is a newer feature, not available when you likely purchased the iPad last time).

Answer (score 1):

WiFi-only Apple devices do not contain a SIM card tray, unfortunately.